# Is reactance in AC circuit is also alternating?

Tags: ac, capacitance, reactance

Usually the capacitive reactance in a a circuit is represent in phasor form as X(c)= |X(c)|\$\angle 90\$.

If we convert this phasor expression to sinusoidal expression we get.
X(c)= |X(c)|sin(wt-90).

Does this mean that capacitive reactance is also time changing ?

If that is the case then at t=0 we get.

X(c) = |Xc|sin(0-90) = -|Xc|. so at t=0 we are getting negative reactance. I really do not understand how reactance can be negative.

Comment: What does "X(c)= /X(c)/<90 degree" mean? I don't understand the forward slashes (/) and what they mathematically represent. Do you mean "|" as used either side of a variable to represent magnitude? If you do then does the "<" symbol mean "angle"? What about using mathjax i.e. \$\angle{90}\$.

Comment: yes /X(c)/ is the magnitude and <90 degree is the angle of the phasor.

Comment: How components store sinusoidal energy by lagging or leading current by 90deg determines the phasor polarity of the reactive impedance. When an equal + and - reactive impedance are together they cancel out ( at one frequency ) The magnitudes are usually stated in VAR's for grid parts and Z(f)= R+jX(f) in this domain

Comment: I've edited it but you better take a CAREFUL look to see it still represents what you originally meant it to

Comment: can you answer @Andyaka

Comment: "If we convert this phasor expression to sinusoidal expression". Ay, there's the rub.

Comment: what ? @SredniVashtar

Comment: Voltage and current are phasors (well, can be represented as such). The reactance is just a complex number that tell you how their amplitude and phases are related. There is no 'conversion to sinusoidal expression' for X.

Comment: are you sure about that @SredniVashtar ? is reactance is always constant for given voltage and current and is not time changing like ac voltages and currents ?

Comment: Augh! Me no speak with forked tongue. Voltages and currents in AC steady state vary with time with sinusoidal dependence. Their relations in amplitude and phase require only a complex number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the current for an inductor and the current for a capacitor when applied the same sine wave voltage: -

[image]

Clearly the capacitor current and inductor current are 180 degrees apart. Clearly they also both have equal magnitudes of reactance when operating at this frequency with those values of C and L.

This means that if one reactance is positive then the other has to be negative.

Comment: is reactance also time changing or its constant. someone claims "For an ideal capacitor or inductor reactance remains the same with varying voltage since the current changes when you change the voltage. " while other claims. "The current through a capacitor always leads the resulting Voltage across the capacitor by 90 degrees which is one fourth of a cycle. Thus the instantaneous reactance [(instantaneous Vc)/(instantaneous Ic)] of a capacitor is constantly changing during each cycle of an ac sine wave Voltage that is applied to a capacitor. @andy aka

Comment: Clearly, on the face of it dividing instantaneous sine by cos appears to equal tan and as an impedance that looks a total mess. It works for a resistor of course but that's just one case. Reactive or any complex impedance uses rotating vectors (or phasors) to resolve what seems to be the anomaly.

Comment: really id didnt understand much what you said. can you please explain ? i just need to know that whether reactance is time changing or its constant in an ideal inductor or capacitor ? not much is clearly written on this in my book.

Comment: Reactance is constant by definition providing that the RMS current and RMS voltage rise and fall together (not the instantaneous values) and that any phase difference between current and voltage is also constant: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/ac-inductance.html

Comment: thanks alot. are you on face book ? may i add you please? @andy aka

Comment: Yes you can add me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46104/discussion-between-alex-and-andy-aka).

Comment: whats your email adress for fb ?

Comment: @Alex - it's on my profile page on SE - just click on "andy aka" and it will take you there. Hey it might go to my music website (a bit crappy) but my facebook name is James Oakwood.